# Oracle Apex &APEX$NEW_START_DATE incorrect output

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

How can I get the selected date from Oracle Apex Calendar without having backslashes?

I tried lots of methods:

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:9:&SESSION.::NO:RP:P9_START:&APEX$NEW_START_DATE.

f?p=&APP_ID.:9:&SESSION.::NO:RP:P9_START:&APEX$NEW_START_DATE.\

f?p=&APP_ID.:9:&SESSION.::NO:RP:P9_START:\&APEX$NEW_START_DATE.\
```

This is resulting in:

```
apex.navigation.dialog.close(true,'f?p=22338:9:15770407909956::NO:RP:P9_START:\02-05-2018\');
```

If I double the last backslash, it works but still the output is incorrect. Ex.: 8th of May 2018:'�8-05-2018\'.

I really need help. I searched all resources available and I can't find anything.

Comment: This thread may interest you https://community.oracle.com/message/14816333

Comment: @Scott apparently my problem was caused because i had my calendar into modal . Switched to normal page and the parameter is sent correctly.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for the follow-up. That's good to know it was because it was a modal page. Strange, but good to know!

Comment: @StewS2 no problem . I don’t understand why from modal sends \ as code and from normal page sends \ and keep this form .